# Rails 4 routing issue, or something else; I am not sure at this point

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, controller, routes

Okay, these dashboard pages originally worked when I was trying to render them within the main controller generated with scaffold.  I opted to try and split them off into their own controller.  I am copying much of this from another app, but it is rails 3 and I am using rails 4.  Also I only have a single model order.rb where the queries for generating the charts resides.

Routes.rb:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  resources :orders do   
    collection do
      get :search, as: 'search'
    end
  end

  namespace :dashboards do
    get 'chart_needby_monthly'
    get 'chart_total_orders_by_qty'
    get 'chart_qty_monthly'
  end

  root 'orders#landing'
end
```

Controller:

```
class DashboardsController < ApplicationController

  def chart_needby_monthly
    logger.info 'I’m inside the controller function, the value of params is: #{params([:dyear])}'

    year = ((params[:dyear]).gsub(/\D/,'')

    logger.info 'After assignmnet,  dyear is: #{dyear}'

    @chart_data_one = Order.search_one(year)
  end

  def chart_total_orders_by_qty
    @chart_data_two = Order.search_two(year)
  end

  def chart_qty_monthly    
    @chart_data_three = Order.search_three(year)
  end

  private 
    def chart_needby_monthly_params
      params.require(:dyear)
    end
end
```

chart_needby_monthly.html.erb

```
<div align = "center">
  <h3>Please Choose the Year for the Dashboard</h3>
</div>
<div align = "center">
  <%= form_tag dashboards_chart_needby_monthly_path, method: :get do %>
   <%= text_field_tag :dyear, (params[:dyear] || Time.now.year.to_s), :class => "search-query span3", :placeholder => "Enter the Year", :autofocus => "autofocus", :datatoggle => "tooltip", :title => "Enter a Year" %>
  <% end %>
</div>
</div>
</br>
</br>
    <%= column_chart @chart_data_one, {library: {hAxis: {title: "Month"}, vAxis: {title: "Number of Orders"}, title: "Need By (Month/Year)"}} %>
```

So when I try and navigate to that page I get the 500 something went wrong page.

I know there is some stuff I am missing here.

Here is the intent:

user enters a year in the text_field at the top of the page and hits enter and it re-renders the page for the year entered; it defaults to the current year on first render so that it passes something to the query in the model by default.

I have three different charts on 3 different pages.

Here is the output into the log for the server:

[INFO] (null):0 (null)(): (null): Started GET "/dashboards/chart_needby_monthly" for 10.63.134.10 at 2015-05-18 10:06:06 -0700

So it is trying to do the get, but it never seems to actually get to the controller.  I have been trying to figure this out for 4 days and I can't seem to figure out what I have done wrong.

Oh and here is the routes rake:

```
                       Prefix Verb   URI        Pattern                                     Controller#Action
                       search_orders GET    /orders/search(.:format)                        orders#search
                              orders GET    /orders(.:format)                               orders#index
                                     POST   /orders(.:format)                               orders#create
                           new_order GET    /orders/new(.:format)                           orders#new
                          edit_order GET    /orders/:id/edit(.:format)                      orders#edit
                               order GET    /orders/:id(.:format)                           orders#show
                                     PATCH  /orders/:id(.:format)                           orders#update
                                     PUT    /orders/:id(.:format)                           orders#update
                                     DELETE /orders/:id(.:format)                           orders#destroy
     dashboards_chart_needby_monthly GET    /dashboards/chart_needby_monthly(.:format)      dashboards#chart_needby_monthly
dashboards_chart_total_orders_by_qty GET    /dashboards/chart_total_orders_by_qty(.:format) dashboards#chart_total_orders_by_qty
        dashboards_chart_qty_monthly GET    /dashboards/chart_qty_monthly(.:format)         dashboards#chart_qty_monthly
                                root GET    /                                               orders#landing
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should try and reproduce this on a development environment so you can see the stacktrace, telling you exactly what went wrong rather than just getting a server error.

In your controller action you're doing this:

```
year = ((params[:dyear]).gsub(/\D/,'')
```

But there's an unclosed parenthesis, so you're most likely getting a syntax error. Change it to this to hopefully fix it:

```
year = (params[:dyear]).gsub(/\D/, '')
```

Or even better, this, since you don't need those initial parenthesis there:

```
year = params[:dyear].gsub(/\D/, '')
```

You've got another mistake in other controller actions though. In `chart_total_orders_by_qty` and `chart_qty_monthly` you're referring to an undefined local variable `year`. The easiest fix is to extract it into its own method:

```
class DashboardsController < ApplicationController

  def chart_needby_monthly
    @chart_data_one = Order.search_one(year)
  end

  def chart_total_orders_by_qty
    @chart_data_two = Order.search_two(year)
  end

  def chart_qty_monthly    
    @chart_data_three = Order.search_three(year)
  end

  private
  def year
    params[:dyear].gsub(/\D/, '')
  end
end
```

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to say I was trying to get just the first one working at all and had not made any changes to the other two charts in the controller.  However, when I did the private class for year as you suggest I get an undefined method for nil class on that now.

Comment: In that case the value of `params[:dyear]` is `nil`. Depending on your requirements there are different ways to handle that case. One option would be to use a default year if none has been supplied with `params.fetch(:dyear, '2015').gsub(/\D/, '')`, where 2015 is used as a default if the `dyear` param isn't present.

Comment: I think I need to set year in the controller if I am going to do it this way, instead of on the erb page.  so I think it needs to be Time.now.year.to_s || params[:dyear].gsub(/\D/,'')

Comment: ended up with 

    def year
      params.fetch(:dyear, Time.now.year)
    end

and then I am setting :dyear on the erb file with the .gsub

Comment: There are many approaches to it, but try to keep your view as simple as possible, so as little logic as possible should be there. If your original question has been answered, please mark the answer as accepted.

Comment: actually did it in controller like I should:

  def year
      year = params[:dyear]
      year ||= Time.now.year.to_s
      year.gsub(/\D/,'') 
    end

thank you very much; this was frustrating.  Now I have to fix the query as it isn't doing exactly what I expect yet.  I should be able to hammer that out though.